# Display image when bool variable is true

Tags: ios, objective-c, image

How can i do this:
I have 5 incentive images. I need to display each image if my bool variable is true.

Here's What I did:

```
BOOL var1 = true;
BOOL var2 = true;
BOOL var3 = false;
BOOL var4 = true;
BOOL var5 = false;

    if(var1)
    {
        cell.incentive1.hidden = false;
    }
    if(var2)
    {
        cell.incentive2.hidden = false;
    }
    if(var3)
    {
        cell.incentive3.hidden = false;
    }
    if(var4)
    {
        cell.incentive4.hidden = false;
    }
    if(var5)
    {
        cell.incentive5.hidden = false;
    }
```

this is working..
I have a follow up question,
how will i be able to display the var4's uiimageview var2's uiimageview. I need the uiimageview to be dynamically created. That when the app detects the bool variables that are true there will be no gaps.

thanks..

Comment: Change all condition to if.

Comment: This code should work (that is mark the desired IV as not hidden) only in the case when only one of the vars can be true. If the images overlap or you have multiple positive vars, the code needs to be changed accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use if...else as all images are independent. You should:

```
if(var1)
    {
        cell.incentive1.hidden = false;
    }

if(var2)
    {
        cell.incentive2.hidden = false;
    }

if(var3)
    {
        cell.incentive3.hidden = false;
    }

if(var4)
    {
        cell.incentive4.hidden = false;
    }

if(var5)
    {
        cell.incentive5.hidden = false;
    }
```

Comment: i have another question @kilogen9 can you please see my update..
thank you very much.. :)

Comment: You can dynamically create UIImageView. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImageView/initWithImage: Then addSubview to your root view or the view to show the image. Also, you should setFrame to position the imageview.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `if..else if` condition, if any one condition passes then the remaining will not be evaluated.

So for fixing the issue, you need to change all to `if` conditions.

But I'll suggest using like following is a better approach (There is no need of if else conditions):

```
cell.incentive1.hidden = !var1;
cell.incentive2.hidden = !var2;
cell.incentive3.hidden = !var3;
cell.incentive4.hidden = !var4;
cell.incentive5.hidden = !var5;
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got chained `if..else if` statements going on there. This means that once one of the conditions is satisfied, the entire evaluation is done and it jumps to the next bit of code. Remove the `else` everywhere, so that every condition is evaluated in isolation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
cell.incentive1.hidden = (var1 == true)?true:false;
cell.incentive2.hidden = (var2 == true)?true:false;
cell.incentive3.hidden = (var3 == true)?true:false;
cell.incentive4.hidden = (var4 == true)?true:false;
cell.incentive5.hidden = (var5 == true)?true:false;
```

Answer (score -1):

As given code if var 1 is true then it will goes to 1st block other wise it goes to next.

and best way to hide and display images you can set alpha 0 for hide and 1 for display.